# Building an OOP Calculator in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I am building an OOP calculator in PHP and I think I started off decent. I have an HTML-file:

```
<?php
require_once("includes/initialize.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Huiswerk week 2</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<?php if (isset($error)) : ?>
    <span class="error"><?php print $error; ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if (empty($calculation)) : ?>
    <form action="index.php" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Rekenmachine</legend>
            <label for="first-number">Getal 1</label><input type="number" id="first-number" name="first-number "/>
            <label for="second-number">Getal 2</label><input type="number" id="second-number" name="second-number"/>

            <input type="radio" id="countUp" value="countUp" name="option"/><label for="countUp">+</label>
            <input type="radio" id="countDown" value="countDown" name="option"/><label for="countDown">-</label>
            <input type="radio" id="divide" value="divide" name="option"/><label for="divide">/</label>
            <input type="radio" id="multiply" value="multiply" name="option"/><label for="multiply">*</label>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Uitvoeren"/>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php

if (is_numeric($_POST["first-number"]) && is_numeric($_POST["second-number"])) {
    switch ($_POST["option"]) {
        case "countUp":
            $calc = new Calculator();
            $result = $calc->countUp($_POST["first-number"], $_POST["second-number"]);
            echo $result;
            break;
        case "countDown":
            $calc = new Calculator();
            $result = $calc->countDown($_POST["first-number"], $_POST["second-number"]);
            echo $result;
            break;
        case "divide":
            $calc = new Calculator();
            $result = $calc->divide($_POST["first-number"], $_POST["second-number"]);
            echo $result;
            break;
        case "multiply":
            $calc = new Calculator();
            $result = $calc->divide($_POST["first-number"], $_POST["second-number"]);
            echo $result;
            break;
        default:
            $error = "Something went terribly wrong.";
            echo $error;
            break;
    }
} else {
    $error = "One of the given numbers is not numeric.";
    echo $error;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The include from the index.php is as follows:

```
<?php
// Require needed files
require_once "settings.php";
require_once "classes/Calculator.php";

try{


} catch (Exception $e){
    $error = "Oops, try to fix your error please: " . $e->getMessage() . " on line " . $e->getLine() . " of " . $e->getFile();
}
```

And the Calculator class is defined in this file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Class Calculator
 */
class Calculator {
    public function __construct(){

    }

    /**
     * @param $firstNumber
     * @param $secondNumber
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function countUp($firstNumber, $secondNumber){
        $result = $firstNumber + $secondNumber;
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @param $firstNumber
     * @param $secondNumber
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function countDown($firstNumber, $secondNumber){
        $result = $firstNumber - $secondNumber;
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @param $firstNumber
     * @param $secondNumber
     * @return float
     */
    public function divide($firstNumber, $secondNumber){
        $result = $firstNumber / $secondNumber;
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @param $firstNumber
     * @param $secondNumber
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function multiply($firstNumber, $secondNumber){
        $result = $firstNumber * $secondNumber;
        return $result;
    }
}
```

The assignment is to have a form that collects two values and four options (+, -, /, *). The given numbers will be used for the chosen calculation. The calculator has to be OOP, and when an error occurs (like when input is not a number), the page will go back to the form with the two inputs intact.

How should I start off from here? I have tried declaring two vars and using a switch in the Calculator class, but it would not work.

Comment: Can you narrow the problem down to a section of code, and paste that into the question instead of pasteboard links? We generally ask code to be inline here, so that it isn't dependent on brittle links, and for the convenience of readers.

Comment: Additionally, if you can show _what_ you've tried, and what you mean by "it would not work", your question will be clearer.

Comment: I have embedded the code in the post itself, thank you for pointing that out.

@halfer: I have tried defining variables inside and outside of the class Calculator to capture the two values put in by the user. I have also tried executing the function within the class based on the result of a switch.

I can not give the precise errors or the precise code I have used, I am sorry about that. The problem I am facing is, how can I easily execute the functions?

Comment: It looks like you are posting to "includes/classes/Calculator.php", which is your class, and will do nothing. You need to post to "index.php", and then use your user input to interact with the `$calculator` instance.

Comment: @halfer: So I suppose I need to execute Calculator::countUp($val1, $val2) in index.php, for example?

Comment: Yes, that's how I would do it.

Comment: I'm getting an Error: undefined index: first-number, but I suppose nothing is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your form as it stands will do nothing. An input like this:

```
<input type="number" id="first-number" />
```

must have a `name` attribute in order to return a value. Try this:

```
<input type="number" id="first-number" name="first-number" />
```

The `id` is still useful for attaching per-item events and attaching `label`s, so I would keep that in.

Secondly, you are accessing the `$_POST` superglobal even when viewing the page normally i.e. in a `get` operation. One solution to that is to wrap your existing `if` statement thusly:

```
if ($_POST) {
    if (is_numeric($_POST["first-number"]) && is_numeric($_POST["second-number"])) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

That way, you'll only be accessing `post` data when the user submits the form.

Comment: Alright, edit the question please with the latest state of your files, and I'll take another look.

Comment: Right, I've edited my answer. The basis of the problem is that you are accessing an array index that does not exist - when viewing the page normally, I think `$_POST` does not exist at all, in fact. Try that first, but arguably a `get` method is better here, since it is easier to work with and you are not modifying server state in the form operation.

Comment: I have tried the conditional checking if `$_POST` exists, after submitting the form the same error would still be popping up about "first-number", same error when changing form to `GET` and all of the conditionals to `$_GET`.

Comment: Stick with post for now. In your `if ($_POST)` section, do `print_r($_POST); exit();` to see what indexes you have. These should correspond to the controls in your form.